# XSLT 1 - find child node where node has case-insensitive value

Tags: xslt, xpath, xquery, xslt-1.0, case-insensitive

I have the following selector, which works:

```
parent::node()/myNS:expField[myNS:Nam='NAMETOFIND']/myNS:Val
```

What I want is to do case-insensitive matching on the `myNS:Nam` value, so I would be able to select `<Val>` from any of the following:

```
<expField>
    <Nam>NAMETOFIND</Nam>
    <Val>the value I want</Val>
</expField>
<expField>
    <Nam>NameToFind</Nam>
    <Val>the value I want</Val>
</expField>
<expField>
    <Nam>nametofind</Nam>
    <Val>the value I want</Val>
</expField>
<expField>
    <Nam>nAmEtOFInD</Nam>
    <Val>the value I want</Val>
</expField>
```

I'm using XSLT 1, so I can't use `lower-case()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`translate()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-translate) will do the job, it's not pretty but it works. If you know what language you want to process, that is.

Comment: Okay, how would I work `translate()` into the `[myNS:Nam='NAMETOFIND']`?  Just `[translate(myNS:Nam, 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz', 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ')='NAMETOFIND']`?  I'll try that.

Comment: Yep, that worked!  I've used `translate()` elsewhere in my XSLT, but never thought to use it in a node selector like that.  Thanks!

Comment: @SarahVessels: Seems like a good idea to accept the answer after confirming that "it worked".

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev: done.  Just had to wait until Stack Overflow would allow me to accept it--there's a delay to allow others to respond.